# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 - JSClassCreate

Tags: ios, react-native

I am getting **Undefined symbols for architecture arm64** when building react-native application in release variant. I deployed the app last month on the store without any problem and now I made some changes and wanted to update it but I cannot build it.

I have tried:  

**- Deleting .rncache 

- Deleting DerivedData 

- Deleting the Build Folder 

- Removing libReact.a and adding it again 

- Setting Dead Code Stripping to No 

- Deleting node_modules and reinstalling them**

Other solutions that i encountered that led me to setting: 
**- Valid architectures: arm64 armv7 armv7s 

- Other Linker Flags: -ObjC -lc++** 

did not work either. 
Can anyone help me with this problem ?

**More specific info about the bug :**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_JSClassCreate", referenced from:
      void std::__1::__call_once_proxy<std::__1::tuple<facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::$_0&&> >(void*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      void std::__1::__call_once_proxy<std::__1::tuple<facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::$_1&&> >(void*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSContextGetGlobalObject", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::global() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSEvaluateScript", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::evaluateJavaScript(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSGlobalContextCreateInGroup", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::JSCRuntime() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::JSCRuntime() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSGlobalContextRelease", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::JSCRuntime() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::~JSCRuntime() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::JSCRuntime() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSGlobalContextRetain", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::JSCRuntime(OpaqueJSContext*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectCallAsConstructor", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::callAsConstructor(facebook::jsi::Function const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectCallAsFunction", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::call(facebook::jsi::Function const&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectCopyPropertyNames", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getPropertyNames(facebook::jsi::Object const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectGetPrivate", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getHostObject(facebook::jsi::Object const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getHostFunction(facebook::jsi::Function const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::HostObjectProxy::finalize(OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::HostObjectProxy::getProperty(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*, OpaqueJSString*, OpaqueJSValue const**) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::HostObjectProxy::setProperty(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*, OpaqueJSString*, OpaqueJSValue const*, OpaqueJSValue const**) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::HostObjectProxy::getPropertyNames(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*, OpaqueJSPropertyNameAccumulator*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      ...
  "_JSObjectGetProperty", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getProperty(facebook::jsi::Object const&, facebook::jsi::String const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getProperty(facebook::jsi::Object const&, facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectGetPropertyAtIndex", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getValueAtIndex(facebook::jsi::Array const&, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectGetPrototype", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectHasProperty", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::hasProperty(facebook::jsi::Object const&, facebook::jsi::String const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::hasProperty(facebook::jsi::Object const&, facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectIsFunction", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::isFunction(facebook::jsi::Object const&) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectMake", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::makeObjectValue(OpaqueJSValue*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectMakeArray", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createArray(unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectSetPrivate", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::HostObjectProxy::finalize(OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::finalize(OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectSetProperty", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::setPropertyValue(facebook::jsi::Object&, facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::setPropertyValue(facebook::jsi::Object&, facebook::jsi::String const&, facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createArray(unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectSetPropertyAtIndex", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::setValueAtIndexImpl(facebook::jsi::Array&, unsigned long, facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectSetPrototype", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSPropertyNameAccumulatorAddName", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::HostObjectProxy::getPropertyNames(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*, OpaqueJSPropertyNameAccumulator*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSPropertyNameArrayGetCount", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getPropertyNames(facebook::jsi::Object const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSPropertyNameArrayGetNameAtIndex", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getPropertyNames(facebook::jsi::Object const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSPropertyNameArrayRelease", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getPropertyNames(facebook::jsi::Object const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::evaluateJavaScript(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::makeStringValue(OpaqueJSString*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createPropNameIDFromAscii(char const*, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createPropNameIDFromUtf8(unsigned char const*, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createStringFromUtf8(unsigned char const*, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::(anonymous namespace)::getLengthString() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      ...
  "_JSStringGetMaximumUTF8CStringSize", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::(anonymous namespace)::JSStringToSTLString(OpaqueJSString*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSStringGetUTF8CString", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::(anonymous namespace)::JSStringToSTLString(OpaqueJSString*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSStringIsEqual", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::compare(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::strictEquals(facebook::jsi::String const&, facebook::jsi::String const&) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSStringRelease", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::evaluateJavaScript(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::JSCStringValue::invalidate() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createPropNameIDFromAscii(char const*, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createPropNameIDFromUtf8(unsigned char const*, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSStringRetain", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::JSCStringValue::JSCStringValue(OpaqueJSString*, std::__1::atomic<long>&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::JSCStringValue::JSCStringValue(OpaqueJSString*, std::__1::atomic<long>&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::makeStringValue(OpaqueJSString*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsArray", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::isArray(facebook::jsi::Object const&) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsBoolean", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsInstanceOfConstructor", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::instanceOf(facebook::jsi::Object const&, facebook::jsi::Function const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsNull", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsNumber", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsObject", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsObjectOfClass", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::isHostObject(facebook::jsi::Object const&) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::isHostFunction(facebook::jsi::Function const&) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsString", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsUndefined", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueMakeBoolean", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::valueRef(facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueMakeNull", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::valueRef(facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueMakeNumber", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::valueRef(facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createArray(unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueMakeString", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::valueRef(facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueMakeUndefined", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::valueRef(facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::HostObjectProxy::getProperty(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*, OpaqueJSString*, OpaqueJSValue const**) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::call(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*, OpaqueJSValue*, unsigned long, OpaqueJSValue const* const*, OpaqueJSValue const**) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueProtect", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::JSCObjectValue::JSCObjectValue(OpaqueJSContext*, std::__1::atomic<bool> const&, OpaqueJSValue*, std::__1::atomic<long>&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::JSCObjectValue::JSCObjectValue(OpaqueJSContext*, std::__1::atomic<bool> const&, OpaqueJSValue*, std::__1::atomic<long>&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::makeObjectValue(OpaqueJSValue*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueToBoolean", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueToNumber", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueToObject", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueToStringCopy", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueUnprotect", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::JSCObjectValue::invalidate() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_kJSClassDefinitionEmpty", referenced from:
      void std::__1::__call_once_proxy<std::__1::tuple<facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::$_0&&> >(void*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      void std::__1::__call_once_proxy<std::__1::tuple<facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::$_1&&> >(void*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Make sure `JavaScriptCore.framework` is added to `Link Binary With Libraries`

Comment: Thanks, i will check on Monday if it helps. But i think i added it this morning, not sure if it was the same one and still got error. Does the order of the libraries matter ? Sorry for the dumb questions, i'm new to xcode & ios development and still don't have the right picture of how it all works.

Comment: Cool, it works now. I had used it before too but the problem was it was added above libReact.a and probably that was causing the problem. I added it before libReact and now it works. But i get this Error now:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_RCTSharedApplication", referenced from: [pakomakTests testRendersWelcomeScreen] in pakomakTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Except RCTSharedApplication the same lines of error are added for RCTDefaultLogFunction and RCTSetLogFunction.

Comment: i have same problem, and insert JavaScriptCore.framework "Link Binary With Libraries" don't working for me for build.. only on simulator.

Comment: This answer is also useful and correct if you are upgrading RN to 0.59.4 and using Xcode 10.2. Thanks @Marc you saved my day

Comment: This worked for me, but I wonder why it's necessary to do this. Isn't there a way for the React Native framework to depend on this? Seems like this will trip up new RN developers.

Comment: @FatihAyyildiz Your comment proved to be useful.

Comment: There is actually one more step to this I believe, you have to run `react-native link`.

Comment: I have JavaScriptCore.framework in my "Link Binary With Libraries", but my application is throwing exception on start up and app stuck on white screen, i am on react-native v0.60.4, is there any additional steps?

Comment: "Link Binary With Libraries" is found under build phases once clicked on the target "your app name"

Comment: freaking genius

Comment: Yes, It is working. In my case i was getting error in ProjectNameTest so i did in test with cocoapods

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar problem when I compile a release version to target "Test". (Didn't encounter when compile to a debug version)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_RCTSetLogFunction", referenced from:
      -[citieswegoTests testRendersWelcomeScreen] in citieswegoTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I try to remove options "arm64 & arm7" from the "valid Architectures" in target "Tests" and the problem is resolved. Hope this help.

1. Change the "select a project or target" e.g Tests.
2. remove "arm64 & arm7" from "valid Architectures"
3. compile your project with release mode.

> ```
>   SDKs:
>     iOS SDK:
>       Platforms: iOS 12.4, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.4, watchOS 5.3
>   IDEs:
>     Xcode: 10.3/10G8 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
>   npmPackages:
>     react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6 
>     react-native: 0.60.5 => 0.60.5 
>   npmGlobalPackages:
>     react-native-cli: 2.0.1
>     react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
>     react-native-macos-cli: 2.0.1
> ```